# android browser java script problem

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am writing a webapp

the code goes like this. i am trying to show a progress bar popup on start of page load. in IE and firefox it runs good, but in android browser it is not even loading ! wheres the problem ? how to debug ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mainpage</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function modalWin() {
//alert("coming");
    if (window.showModalDialog) {
    window.showModalDialog("pb.html","name","dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
    } else {
    window.open('xpopupex.htm','name','height=100,width=100,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,modal=yes');
    }
    }
    </script>
</head>


<body onLoad=modalWin()>
    <frameset rows="5%, *" border="10"> 
        <frame src="header.html">  

<frame src="footer.html">
        </frameset>

    </frameset>

  <noframes>
    You are using an old browser.
</noframes>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Framesets are pretty dated, I wonder if it simply does'nt like framesets.

Comment: Popup windows make baby Jesus cry.

Comment: Have you enabled the JavaScript. See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29

Comment: @Mudassir That's for when you're using `WebView` in your Android application; I believe the OP is talking about the regular web browser on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your HTML is wrong.  Frameset replaces body, you don't have frameset and body together.  Frameset and body have [different DOCTYPEs](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html).  Your code doesn't even load the frameset in Google Chrome unless you remove the body element.

As for frameset mobile support in general.  I don't see why not, but I wouldn't choose them personally, because I imagine they would be more difficult to use on a small screen.  ([They're not in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#absent-elements) anyway)

How to debug?  Hmm, you could try [validating](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) before debugging.  Then if you still have an issue with valid code, on a problem like this, it would be a case of iteratively reducing the code until you have narrowed down to the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to:

```
 if (window.showModalDialog) {
    window.showModalDialog("pb.html","name","dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
    } else {
    window.open('xpopupex.htm','name','height=100,width=100,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,modal=yes');
    }
```

In Android Browser this code `window.showModalDialog` launches `true` but that browser can't render this method.

This method is only supported by IE. Recently Firefox 28 deprecated `showModalDialog` and Chrome 35 removed it. You can change your code, checking the user agent instead:

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>-1) {
    window.showModalDialog("pb.html","name","dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
    } else {
    window.open('xpopupex.htm','name','height=100,width=100,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,modal=yes');
    }
```